# Finding SharePoint Site Collection using just it's GUID

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am currently working with some code that gives me the following:

- Site Collection Guid

I would like to fetch the site url using the site collection Guid with PNP PowerShell.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: what is the exact issue? Do you want to retrieve the GUID of site collection using site URL or retrieve URL of Site collection using GUID?

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft Graph can provide you the information about the site collection. See the paragraph [Note for existing SharePoint developers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0) and especially the last example.

The endpoint URL for your use case would then be

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname},{spsite-id}`

Resulting URL for tenant `mytenant.sharepoint.com` and site collection `21e6689e-ddd0-48eb-1234-0357c5fa1093`:

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com,21e6689e-ddd0-48eb-1234-0357c5fa1093`

The response then looks like this:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites/$entity",
    "createdDateTime": "2018-01-12T21:27:53.963Z",
    "description": "",
    "id": "mytenant.sharepoint.com,21e6689e-ddd0-48eb-1234-0357c5fa1093,2cb44c34-5aee-4c5e-1234-9a2d36b8204b",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-04-02T10:58:01Z",
    "name": "mysitecollection",
    "webUrl": "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecollection",
    "displayName": "My Site Collection",
    "root": {},
    "siteCollection": {
        "hostname": "mytenant.sharepoint.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit - Below will work only for SP on premises environment.

I think you can use Pure Powershell command.

```
Get-SPSite -Identity "121321-12312-12312-1231231"
```

Identity parameter takes url or GUID, below is text from microsoft documentation

*-Identity
Specifies the URL or GUID of the site collection to get.
The type must be a valid URL, in the form, https://server_name or https://server_name/sites/sitename, or a valid GUID (for example, 12345678-90ab-cdef-1234-567890bcdefgh).*

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps

Hope this helps...Happy Coding..!!!

Comment: This will only work when executed in a PowerShell on an OnPremise SharePoint Server, but not in SharePoint Online.

Comment: @Anon.... true... my bad... I just checked PnP documentation, it does not accept GUID.